# how to find location of specific <tr> each time code is run

Tags: html, vba, excel, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

My code below will extract a value for each hour of the day.

However, the webpage I'm scraping can change and so I want to find a way to assign the location of the  to a variable so that it will know what number it is everytime. I found the current number "116" by trial and error.

I included the html structure below as well. Any suggestions?

```
Sub scrape()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "web address"
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .document.all.item("Login1_UserName").Value = "user"
        .document.all.item("Login1_Password").Value = "pw"
        .document.all.item("Login1_LoginButton").Click
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    Dim htmldoc As Object
    Dim r
    Dim c
    Dim aTable As Object
    Dim TDelement As Object
    Set htmldoc = IE.document

    Dim td As Object
    For Each td In htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
        On Error Resume Next
        If span.Children(0).id = "ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl08_Label50" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("j8").Offset(r, c).Value = td.Children(1).innerText
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next td
End Sub
```

HTML:

```html
<form name="aspnetForm" id="aspnetForm" action="./MinMaxReport.aspx" 
method="post">
<div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<div>
</div>
<table class="header-table">...</table>
<table class="page-area">              
<tbody>
<tr>
<table id="ctl00_PageContent_Table1" border="0">...</table>
<table id="ctl00_PageContent_Table2" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_div">
<tbody>
<tr style="background-color: beige;">
<td>...</td>
<td>
<span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl08_Label50">Most Restrictive 
Capacity Maximum</span>
</td>
<td>
<span id="ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl08_Label51">159</span>
</td>                                     
</tr>  
</tbody>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</table>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all TDs and check if id= "ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl08_Label50" for example:

```
For Each td In htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    On Error Resume Next
        If td.Children(0).ID = "ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl08_Label50" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("j8").Offset(r, c).Value = td.Children(1).innerText
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next td
```

Children(0) will pick the first iHTML element contained in your table cell. On Error Resume Next is for the situation when td element has no child. 
It is possible that you have more then one element with this id in your webpage. Then, you must identify table or table row first. I cannot do it because I can't see your whole HTML code.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, however when I run my code with your suggested loop, it failed to return anything. I also tried replacing "td" with "span" and got the same result. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Can you find this string by Ctrl+F in your website's source: ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl08_Label50

Comment: Yes I am able to find it using Ctrl+F in the source code.

Comment: I found that using childnodes.item(0).id returns data but using children(0).id does not return data. However, the data returned by using childnodes still isn't returning the innertext of: "ctl00_PageContent_grdReport_ctl08_Label50".

Comment: I've updated my html code that shows the whole html.